# Example ideal of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: lie-algebras, examples-counterexamples

I need an example about ideal from lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ except trivial ideal and $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ itself, can someone help me?

I try to make ideal except trivial ideal and $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ itself, but I got stuck.

Comment: There aren't any... sl(2,$\mathbb{C}$) is a simple Lie algebra.  This Lie algebra is small enough that it isn't too hard to prove directly.

Comment: @Ted can you give me an example not simple lie algebra and its ideal?

Comment: Take the 2-dimensional Lie algebra with bracket defined by $[x,y]=y$. The the scalar multiples of $y$ is an ideal.

Comment: @Ted Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 4):

We claim that $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ is a simple Lie algebra.

To see this, note that $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ is 3-dimensional with basis $\{H, X, Y\}$ with the Lie brackets $$[H,X] = 2X$$ $$[H,Y] = 2Y$$ $$[X,Y]=H.$$

From the above relations, if an ideal contains one of $H$, $X$, or $Y$, then it is all of 
$\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$, so it is sufficient to show that a nonzero ideal contains a nonzero multiple of one of $H$, $X$, or $Y$.

So suppose an ideal contains a nonzero element $U = aH + bX + cY$.  Then the ideal also contains $$[U,X] = -cH +  2aX $$ 
$$[U,Y] = bH + 2aY$$
and thus also
$$[[U,X],X] = -2cX$$
$$[[U,Y],Y] = 2bY$$
Hence, if either $b \ne 0 $ or $c \ne 0$ we are done, and if $b=c=0$ then we must have $a \ne 0$ (since $U \ne 0$) and hence $U$ is a nonzero multiple of $H$ and we are also done.