# A theorem about semisimple Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

I'm reading *Lie Groups, Lie Algebras , and Representations* (first edition) by Hall and I'm stuck by a theorem (The author did not prove it):

> Theorem 6.6 A complex Lie algebra is semisimple if and only if it is isomorphic to the complexification of the Lie algebra  of a simply-connected compact matrix Lie group.

Through this theorem (assume it is right) we can prove that $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ is semisimple, but $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ is in fact simple.  There is a proof : [Example ideal of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271387/example-ideal-of-mathfraksl2-mathbbc)

So whether is the theorem right or wrong? If it is wrong, is there any correct theorem related to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, one could assume that there's some contradiction somewhere. Where is it? Yes, $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ is simple and, yes, $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ is semisimple. That's not a problem, since every simple Lie algebra is also semisimple.

Comment: So you mean Theorem 6.6 is correct ? And could you give me a hint on why "every simple Lie algebra is also semisimple"?

Comment: @Kokuto This is more or less trivial, depending on the definition of semisimple Lie algebra. In most cases (but IIRC not in Hall's book) semisimple Lie algebra is defined to be a direct sum of simple Lie algebras, of which simple Lie algebra is obviously an example.

Comment: Yes, [theorem 6.6 is correct.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_Lie_algebra#Connection_with_compact_Lie_groups). And you will find a proof of the fact that every simple Lie algebra is also semisimple [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405261/a-complex-lie-algebra-is-the-direct-sum-of-simple-ideals-iff-it-is-semisimple).

Comment: @José Carlos Santos  Well. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Cave Johnson   Thanks for your comment :)